# How to read input text file in Java without having to change the filename each time

Tags: java, filereader

I have around 10 input text files with each text file having video parameters. I need to run all of 10 input files and compare the results. Is there a way to run the program without having to change the input filename in the path everytime?

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    File config = new File("C:\\Users\\Dell\\Documents\\DataProcessing\\src\\config6.txt");

    try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(config));
        String st;
        while ((st = br.readLine()) != null) {
            String s[] = st.split("\\r?\\n");
            for (int i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
                arrList.add(s[i]);
            }
        }
        br.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
    }
}
```

I have to change the file name (as shown above,config6.txt) everytime to config4,config5.txt to run other input files. Is there a better and efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

to solve this problem, first read in a file from the user input and validate if it is a valid file, if yes, then continue on in your program. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

```java
List<Integer> replaceNumbers = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10);
String filePath = "C:\\Users\\Dell\\Documents\\DataProcessing\\src\\config0.txt";

for (int f = 0; f < replaceNumbers.size(); f++) {
    File config = new File(filePath.replace("0", replaceNumbers.get(f).toString()));

    try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(config));
        String st;
        while ((st = br.readLine()) != null) {
            String s[] = st.split("\\r?\\n");
            for (int i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
                arrList.add(s[i]);
            }
        }
        br.close();
    } catch (Exception e) { }
}
```

Just replace numbers in `replaceNumbers` list.

Comment: Instead of replacing the value try using [`String::format`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...)) since its more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this. Assuming your first config file is `config0.txt` and last is `config9.txt`.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String formatPath = "C:\\Users\\Dell\\Documents\\DataProcessing\\src\\config%d.txt";

    List<File> files = IntStream.range(0, 10)
            .mapToObj(i -> String.format(formatPath, i))
            .map(File::new).collect(Collectors.toList());

    List<String> arrList = new ArrayList<>();

    for (File file : files)
        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))) {
            String st;
            while ((st = br.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] s = st.split("\\r?\\n");
                for (int i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
                    arrList.add(s[i]);
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

The `IntStream.range(a, b)` method generates a `IntStream` of numbers from `a` (inclusive) to `b` (exclusive).

Also I'm using a `try` block with resources meaning the `br.close()` is implicit. Find out more about `try` with resources [here](https://www.baeldung.com/java-try-with-resources).